# Delphi Server Socket component

Tags: delphi, sockets

We have a C/S application all written in Delphi (Client and Server-or middleware if you want)
For the client part we use Indy.
For the server we use DXSock.

Since DXSock is dead for a while we are investigating alternatives for the sever part.

I want to hear some comments about the best Server Socket alternative component for Delphi.
The current system usually have tens of permanent connections working each one on its own thread but could be hundreads in the future (this should be improved to a thread pool if possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the best possible performance, you'd have to use sockets in non blocking mode, or using [completion ports](http://www.nevelsteen.com/coding/completion_ports_in_delphi.htm). IPWorks is implemented like that, as well as [iocp](http://voipobjects.com/index.php?page=delphi-iocp-library). As far as I can tell, Indy or [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/public) don't implement them (at least officially).

We used completion ports and a thread pool in our open source [SynCrtSock](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=446#p446) unit, used in our [Synopse SQLite3 framework](http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=2).

Here are some benchmarks of this solution, working from Delphi 6 up to Delphi XE. I don't tell this is the "best component", but it's a working and speedy one (every request is about 4 KB of JSON data):

- Http client keep alive (i.e. one HTTP/1.1 client connection kept alive during requests): 
   first in 7.87ms, done in 153.37ms i.e. 6520/s, average 153us
- Http client multi connect (i.e. one new HTTP/1.0 client connection created for each request - this one uses completion ports and a thread pool): 
   first in 151us, done in 305.98ms i.e. 3268/s, average 305us

For speed comparison, here are other communication protocols available in our framework:

- Named pipe access: 
   first in 78.67ms, done in 187.15ms i.e. 5343/s, average 187us
- Local window messages: 
   first in 148us, done in 112.90ms i.e. 8857/s, average 112us
- Direct in process access: 
   first in 44us, done in 41.69ms i.e. 23981/s, average 41us

We use HTTP/1.1 protocol over TCP/IP, because there is very little overhead over plain TCP/IP, and this is a well handled protocol for firewalls and such, and allows our framework to be used by an AJAX application, whereas its main purpose is to serve Delphi clients.

IMHO there is no "best Server Socket alternative component for Delphi", it depends what is the purpose of your server application. The main bottleneck will be in the Windows kernel itself. Perhaps direct access to the [HTTP Kernel-Mode Driver (Http.sys)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364510%28VS.85%29.aspx) of Windows could help.

Consider using a dedicated optimized Server instead of a Delphi server, like [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) or [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) using FastCGI to handle the requests via a Free Pascal (or CrossKylix) application, under Linux. I guess this will be the best performance possible.

Comment: Well I really expected more alternatives. I'm accepting this answer for pointing me to iocp. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've added http.sys support for our HTTP/1.1 server. That is very fast kernel-level support of the HTTP server. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/11/HTTP-server-using-fast-http.sys-kernel-mode-server

Answer (score 2):

I use Indy components for commercial server-side work and the component set is pretty solid  (9 or 10).  My servers have millions of connections per day with no issues.

I used DXSock many moons ago.  He was always optimizing, but never seemed to finish it.  He does seem to have another version out.

If you want commercial support, then I'd recommend IPWorks from nSoftware.

Comment: Indy will work for 100s and probably 1000s of concurrent connections depending how active the connections are, particularly with a multi-core machine. I would look at alternatives only if you need more concurrent connections than that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually DXSock is not dead, v6.1 was just released. The web hosting company we used to use in Tennessee lost the domain - so only customers who have kept their subscription renewed annually have received DXSock 5.0, 6.0 and 6.1.

Indy CANNOT support more than 2,000 concurrent connections on 32bit Windows - as Chad and crew use TThread, which implements the defacto 1MB per thread/socket connection - 2000x1MB = >2.5GB of RAM which 32bit OSes do not support. DXSock implements a 0b per connection model (unless you define otherwise) and can handle over 50,000 concurrent on Windows, Linux, Mac, Pi, etc.

Ozz Nixon - ozznixon@bpdx.com if you want more details on 6.1

Author of DXSock

Co-Author of Winshoes which became INDY.